# Understanding subgroup criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a self learner and beginner in group theory. I study subgroups but something stuck in my mind.Maybe it is because i could not understand the logic of abstract algebra.

It is given that a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup if and
only if

- $H \neq \emptyset$
- for all $x,y \in H$ , $xy^{-1} \in H$

**Where i stuck :** Its proof is ubiquitous , but there is a point in its proof that i could not understand.

When we prove it conversely , we say that lets assume that those both condition holds for $H$.Let $x$ be any element in $H$ because $H \neq \emptyset$. Let $y=x$ and apply the second contion such that $xx^{-1}=1$.

Here , i could not understand how we can say $y=x$ , becasue in the second condition we see that like two different elements by saying for all $x,y \in H$.If we can do it just a single element , why did we give two element $x,y$

Comment: When saying "for all $x,y \in H$", they can be the same. Think for example when saying "For all $x,y$ positives numbres their sum is also positive". Here it's valid to do "2+2" for example.

Comment: Actually, your question is independent of abstract algebra (and its "logic"). It is also, say, in calculus, that if you say "for all $x,y$ in the interval $[0,1]$ we have that $x+y\le 2$", you can have $x=y$ as well.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

The clause "for all $x,y\in H$" allows us the option in general to take $y=x$, since, indeed, the clause holds for all $x\in H$ and does not stipulate that $x\neq y$ in our subsequent choice of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "for all $x,y \in H$" , it does not matter whether $x \neq y$ , $x>y$,$x<y$, $x=y$ . The situation ,i.e $xy^{-1}$ is true for all given cases.

Comment: This is slightly misleading. There are more operations than inequality, and some groups, say $G$, have elements in which, for $a,b\in G$ with $a\neq b$, neither $a<b$ nor $b<a$ hold; for example, in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, the elements are equivalence classes $$[x]_3:=\{y\in\Bbb Z: 3\mid x-y\}.$$ It makes no sense to say $[0]_3<[1]_3$ nor $[0]_3>[1]_3$, since $[0]_3=[3]_3$ and $[1]_3=[4]_3$.